# Argument Error when trying to specify :env in Elixir Port.open

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm trying to set an environment variable when running a shell command using `Port.open`. It raises an error, `ArgumentError` no matter what I pass in.

```
port = Port.open({ :spawn_executable, "/usr/local/bin/cool" },
        [:stream, :in, :binary, :eof, :hide, 
          {:env, [{"COOL_ENV", "cool"}]},
          { :args, ["test.js"] }])
```

According to the Elixir docs for Port.open, it should accept any arguments that the Erlang function :erlang.open_port accepts. The Erlang documentation mentions:

> {env, Env} Only valid for {spawn, Command}, and {spawn_executable,
>   FileName}. The environment of the started process is extended using
>   the environment specifications in Env.
>
> Env is to be a list of tuples {Name, Val}, where Name is the name of
>   an environment variable, and Val is the value it is to have in the
>   spawned port process. Both Name and Val must be strings. The one
>   exception is Val being the atom false (in analogy with os:getenv/1,
>   which removes the environment variable.
>   (http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2)

This error occurs even if I try to call the erlang function directly like so:

```
:erlang.open_port({:spawn_executable, "/usr/local/bin/cool"}, [:stream, :in, :binary, :eof, :hide, {:env, [{"COOL", "cool"}] },{:args, ["test.js"]}])
```

The error goes away if I remove the `{:env, [{...}]` argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:env` option requires both the name and the value to be Erlang strings, which is called a charlist in Elixir, and is constructed using single quotes instead of double.

```
Opt =
    ...
    {env, Env :: [{Name :: string(), Val :: string() | false}]} |
    ...
```

<sup>[Source](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2)</sup>

The following should fix the error:

```
port = Port.open({ :spawn_executable, "/usr/local/bin/cool" },
        [:stream, :in, :binary, :eof, :hide, 
          {:env, [{'COOL_ENV', 'cool'}]},
          { :args, ["test.js"] }])
```

`:args` accepts both Erlang strings and Erlang binaries (Elixir Strings), so you don't need to change that.

Comment: Thank you! You've answered my last 3 elixir questions :D. Is there any easier way to figure errors like this out? The error message was so terse it was almost no help.

Comment: I agree that the error message is unhelpful. Whenever I get an argument error from a function that is in Erlang's standard library, I first check the type signature of the function in the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) and then check whether I'm passing arguments of the right type. If that doesn't help then the last resort is finding the source code of the function and seeing what all failed checks lead to an argument error.

Comment: That answer made my day :-)